# get the rootweb for a office 365 for a site collection

Tags: powershell, office-365, csom

i have a site collection called `https://mysitedev.sharepoint.com/sites/migration`
is there anyway to get the first bit `https://mysitedev.sharepoint.com` with csom. will i have to do it with regex?

Comment: Those are two different site collections (just for clarification)

Comment: yeah, they are in the same farm but are different site collections

Comment: Do you want to get the root site collection or the root web of the root site collection? Online shell contains `Get-SPOSite` for getting a site collection.

Answer (score 0):

As per my knowledge you can not get the tenant site collection url directly.

You can get it by splitting the url by **.**(dot) and then concatenate **firstPart** [https://mydevsite] + **secondPart** [sharepoint] + **thirdPart** [com]